# Validating date format dd-mmm-yyyy and dd mmm yyyy in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to validate two date formats: `DD-MMM-YYYY` and `DD MMM YYYY`.

Here is the code I use to validate DD-MMM-YYYY

```
CASE 
   WHEN (date_column != ' ' 
         AND (ISDATE(date_column) = 0
              OR (ISDATE(date_column) = 1
              AND (CHARINDEX('-', date_column, 0) <> 3 
               OR (CHARINDEX('-', date_column, 4) <>7
               OR (LEN(date_column) <> 11))) 
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0  
END)
```

Here is the code I use to validate DD MMM YYYY:

```
 CASE WHEN ( date_column !=' ' 
       AND ( ISDATE(date_column )=0
           OR ( ISDATE(date_column )=1
               AND ( CHARINDEX(' ',date_column ,0) <>3 
               OR  ( CHARINDEX(' ',date_column ,4) <>7
               OR  (LEN(date_column) <>11
               )
             )
         ) THEN 1
         ELSE 0  END)
```

Can these be combined to populate at a same time instead of two blocks of code?

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: It looks like you have a lot more `(` than `)` in these code snippets. You can definitely combine them - just combine character checks like `(CHARINDEX(' ',...) OR CHARINDEX('-',...) )`

Comment: @Krik Broadhurst : As per your case it is always returning ‘1’ .

Comment: can you tell us what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Lamak : sever 2014

Comment: Why not use TRY_CONVERT or TRY_PARSE? And then go slap the person who decided to store dates as characters.

Comment: Why isn't this column defined as DATETIME or DATETIME2?

Comment: Ideally, don't do this sort of work in the database. By the time data is reaching the database, it should *already* have been parsed (as close to the point of user input as possible) and placed in a variable of an *appropriate* data type (such as `datetime`). The data should be kept in such variables/parameters/columns throughout its journey into and out of the database and only rendered back into a string during *presentation* to the user.

Answer (score 0):

CONVERT the datetime into the format that you want.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Example query: SELECT GETDATE(), CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 120)
Example output: 2018-02-06 14:02:50.900 2018-02-06

Comment: Example query: SELECT GETDATE(), CAST(DATENAME(day, GETDATE()) as varchar) + '-' + CAST(DATENAME(m, GETDATE()) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS varchar)

Example output: 2018-02-06 14:08:34.530 6-February-2018

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql

Comment: Example query: SELECT GETDATE(), CAST(DATENAME(day, GETDATE()) as varchar) + '-' + CAST(DATENAME(m, GETDATE()) AS varchar(3)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS varchar)

Example output: 2018-02-06 14:10:53.570 6-Feb-2018

Comment: You can also do this in reverse too...

Example query: SELECT CAST('6-Feb-2018' AS datetime)
Example output: 2018-02-06 00:00:00.000

Comment: Honestly, if you cannot CAST that string into a datetime, then it's invalid. :)

Comment: I don’t want to cast or convert. Want to validate as it is.

Answer (score 0):

try_parse returns NULL when it is not a valid date. German Culture 'de-de' knows the formats 'dd-mm-yyyy' or 'dd mm yyyy'

```
CASE WHEN TRY_PARSE(date_column AS DATE USING 'de-de') IS NOT NULL 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
END
```